# Attempting modularisation with abstract classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I've been learning to modularise code and I've stumped myself trying to fix a problem that I've had for a while. I have two abstract classes, both of these classes have multiple subclasses. One of the classes tries to make a hashmap to store objects of all the subclasses of the other abstract class. But where I have methods that are individual to some subclasses I can't call them on the objects stored in the hashmap because they are not of the same type. How can I work around this while keeping my code modular?

The hashmap in the first abstract class:

```
protected Map<Ruler, List<Nation> nations = new HashMap<Ruler, List<Nation>();
```

There is then code in one of its subclasses trying to call a method on the objects in the 'Nation' list which only exists in one of the subclasses of Nation. How can I work around this?

Abstract class with the hashmap:

```
public abstract class Ruler {

    protected Ruler ruler;
    protected Map<Ruler, List<Nation> nations = new HashMap<Ruler, List<Nation>();

    public Ruler(Ruler ruler) {
        super();
        this.ruler= ruler;
        this.ruler.put(ruler, new ArrayList<Nation>());;
    }
}

public class Government extends Ruler {
    public Government(Ruler ruler) {
        super(ruler);
    }

    public double totalGovernmentCost() {
        double cost = 0;
        for (Nation nation : this.nations.get(ruler)) {
            cost += nation.calculateGovernmentCost();
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is the second abstract class 'Nation'. Much the same as Ruler. But the subclass with the 'calculateGovernmentCost()' method is GovernmentNation. The error im getting is on:

```
nation.calculateGovernmentCost();
```

Where it compains that 'calculateGovernmentCost()' is undefined for the type Nation.

Comment: Post the classes' declarations.

Comment: Your design is a bit confusing to me. Why does a `Ruler` have a map from `Ruler` to `List<Nation>`s? And why do `Ruler`s have a reference to a `Ruler`? Answering these questions will help decide what the best design is. The easy way to fix your issue is with an `instanceof` check and a cast, but that's not very clean. Generics could probably make things cleaner, if we only understood more about your design constraints.

Comment: I need a modular way (I thought a map might work - but it didnt) to be able to have different subclasses of Ruler and Nation where I can store different Nation subclasses into a Ruler subclass. But currently I can't think of a way to store all the Nations (of any type) that relate to a single ruler type. The way I am doing it has the issue of the Ruler subclasses not being able to access methods within the Nation subclasses.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. Thanks to augray. Generics was the way to go.